# Is there a neurological reason why women do not occupy top positions in the chess ranking?

Tags: neuroscience, cognitive-neuroscience

I want to turn arround this [question posted on chess exchange](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/24917/why-arent-there-any-women-super-gms?noredirect=1#comment38681_24917) where sociological arguments are given to explain why [only two of the world's top 100 chess players are women](https://aeon.co/essays/why-are-only-two-of-the-world-s-top-100-chess-players-women).

Are there neurological evidences to assert, in equal conditions, women would still be worst at chess than men?

Comment: I don't think there is anything to add to that question besides what's already there.

Comment: @Bryan Krause So the reasons are probably sociological and not any cognitive difference between males and females?

Comment: It's not a question that can be separated from the sociology. Training at anything changes the brain. There is no independent neurometric function for "good at chess" or really for anything else except extremely basic psychophysics.